# How to set condition value in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to set a condition

```
 initialValue = {
                this.props.noteviewReducer.isError &&
                this.props.noteviewReducer.result.body
 }
```

`if (this.props.noteviewReducer.isError)` **true** then show `this.props.noteviewReducer.result.body`

if `not`, then **not show**

Comment: try like this `<div> { this.props.noteviewReducer.isError ? this.props.noteviewReducer.result.body : 'NO DATA' } </div>`

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more with proper code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<div>
  {this.props.noteviewReducer.isError && (
    <MyComponent initialValue={this.props.noteviewReducer.result.body} />
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation why this works.